# How to detect Marker's location after draggable

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to get Marker's location after draggable in Google Map. Current is I can add Marker in Google Map according to current location of device in snippet. Now, what I want is try to get Marker's location based on draggable position.

```
placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = { [latitude doubleValue], [longitude doubleValue] };
mymarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
mymarker.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemark.thoroughfare];
mymarker.appearAnimation = YES;
mymarker.flat = YES;
mymarker.snippet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@, %@ %@", placemark.locality, placemark.administrativeArea, placemark.postalCode, placemark.country];
mymarker.map = _mapView;
mymarker.draggable = true;
```

Comment: did you try this -(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker method

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
        NSLog(@"New location of marker: Lat: %f, Long: %f", marker.position.latitude, marker.position.longitude);
}
```